# Retrieve post value in the controller sent by ajax call

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I am unable to retrieve value sent as a post through ajax call in cake php controller file

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "share",
        data: country,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                // Success!
            } else {
                    console.log(response.data, response.code);
            }
        }
    });
```

I have tried with the below ways of retrieving the data sent in the above code through POST. But none of them worked.

```
$this->params
$this->data
$_POST[]
$this->request
```

The url points to the function in the controller page.
Please can any of you let me know how the value can be retrieved.

Comment: what are you getting? if you print_r the $_POST array do you get something? are you sure your controller is being hit?

Comment: What version of cake are you using? If 2.x, haven't you tried with `$this->request->data`?

Answer (score 0):

When submitting data via ajax and you want cake to pick it up in the usual way just use `$('whatever').serialize()`.

if you don't have an actual form to serialize you can fake it by submitting the data as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {
        data: country
    },
    ...
});
```

Note how cake generates fields like `data[Model][field]`. you don't need the Model part but the `data` part is important.